# Unable to run freshly updated QGIS 3.14 on Ubuntu 18.04 using libprotobuf-lite version greater than 10

Tags: installation, ubuntu, qgis-3

## Context

*(see bottom EDIT for the fix, thanks to ThomasG77)*

After having run my daily updates using; `apt update && apt upgrade`, on Ubuntu 18.04 I've seen that QGIS 3.14 was newly shipped and installed. That's cool!

But now, I'm not able to open it according to this error:

```
$ qgis
/usr/bin/qgis.bin: error while loading shared libraries:
libprotobuf-lite.so.10: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
```

But I actually have more recent protobuf-lite libraries:

```
$ find /usr -iname "*libprotobuf-lite*"
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.15.0.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.15
/usr/share/doc/libprotobuf-lite10
/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-lite.so
/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-lite.so.18
/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-lite.a
/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-lite.so.18.0.0
/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-lite.la
```

This is my apt source file for QGIS:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.list
deb http://qgis.org/debian bionic main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian bionic main
```

And If I try to reinstall it:

```
$ apt-get install qgis python3-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-qgis is already the newest version (1:3.14.0+28bionic).
qgis is already the newest version (1:3.14.0+28bionic).
qgis-plugin-grass is already the newest version (1:3.14.0+28bionic).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

That's the result:

```
Setting up qgis-providers (1:3.14.0+28bionic) ...
/usr/lib/qgis/crssync: error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf-lite.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package qgis-providers (--configure):
 installed qgis-providers package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis:
 qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.14.0+28bionic); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-qgis:
 python3-qgis depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.14.0+28bionic); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-qgis (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-server:
 qgis-server depends on qgis-providers (= 1:3.14.0+28bionic); however:
  Package qgis-providers is not configured yet.
 qgis-server depends on python3-qgis (= 1:3.14.0+28bionic); however:
  Package python3-qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                               dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qgis-plugin-grass:
 qgis-plugin-grass depends on qgis (= 1:3.14.0+28bionic); however:
  Package qgis is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package qgis-plugin-grass (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 qgis-providers
 qgis
 python3-qgis
 qgis-server
 qgis-plugin-grass
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

## Question

Is this a known issue?
How can I fix it?

Comment: `sudo apt install libprotobuf-lite10` and try also `sudo apt install -f` after to fix the broken install

Comment: This tells me `libprotobuf-lite10 is already the newest version (3.5.1+6-0bionic1).` and then I fall back on the same results. And if I add the `--reinstall` flag to `apt install`, it says: `Reinstallation of libprotobuf-lite10 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.`

Comment: Surprised because https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libprotobuf-lite10 . Moreover, I don't see where your protobuf version comes from (version 15 and 18 are not in the ubuntu repositories e.g https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libprotobuf&searchon=names).

Comment: I remember not very well, but I had to deal with these versions while compiling machine learning stuff some time ago (tensorflow related) which needed at least version 15 of libprotobuf...

Comment: For QGIS (it may break your ML part), download manually libprotobuf-lite10 by downloading https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libprotobuf-lite10/download and install it (if your system does not ask to install do `sudo dpkg -i libprotobuf-lite10_3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`) and try again `apt-install -f`

Comment: It seems OK now (I hope I won't have much troubles with other softwares...). Thanks.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer not an edit to your question so that other people can find it.

Comment: I wish ThomasG77 will do that so that I can give him the deserved credits... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by TomasG77 in the comment above, a manual download (from one of the mirrors here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libprotobuf-lite10/download) **and** reinstall of the `libprotobuff-lite10` package using:

`dpkg -i libprotobuf-lite10_3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

have solved the issue:

```
$ dpkg -i libprotobuf-lite10_3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
dpkg: warning: downgrading libprotobuf-lite10:amd64 from 3.5.1+6-0bionic1 to 3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1
(Reading database ... 705196 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libprotobuf-lite10_3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libprotobuf-lite10:amd64 (3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1) over (3.5.1+6-0bionic1) ...
Setting up libprotobuf-lite10:amd64 (3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Then a simple check on this package with `apt` has directly fixed QGIS pending issues:

```
$ sudo apt install libprotobuf-lite10 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libprotobuf-lite10 is already the newest version (3.0.0-9.1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up qgis-providers (1:3.14.0+28bionic) ...
Setting up python3-qgis (1:3.14.0+28bionic) ...
Setting up qgis-server (1:3.14.0+28bionic) ...
Setting up qgis (1:3.14.0+28bionic) ...
Setting up qgis-plugin-grass (1:3.14.0+28bionic) ...
W: APT had planned for dpkg to do more than it reported back (12 vs 16).
   Affected packages: qgis-providers:amd64
```